# How to set up KVM guest serial console

Tags: centos, gentoo, kvm

I have a gentoo live cd guest running on a CentOS 7 host. I am logged in remotely to the CentOS host trying to perform a remote install and am unable to SSH into the gentoo live cd (because by default SSHD is stopped). I need to complete step 2 on the following site so I can instead use `virsh console` to access the gentoo guest:

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Unable_to_connect_to_console_of_a_running_domain

My question is, how can I edit the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file on the guest so I can use `virsh console` instead of ssh if I don't already have remote access to the machine? It seems like there is not way access the gentoo guest remotely without first having started sshd, which defeats the purpose of a remote install. Suggestions?

Comment: It depends on which grub version your guest use v1 or v2

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just run `virt-viewer qemu+ssh://root@centos-host/gentoo-vm` on your local machine.

That will connect to the VM's console via ssh.

If you need to choose something from the installer boot menu that times out too quickly and disappears before `virt-viewer` connects or before you can choose, then start the VM on the remote host, connect to it with virt-viewer as above, and then `virsh reboot` or `virsh reset` the VM.

Comment: if your local machine isn't linux, see http://www.spice-space.org/download.html for windows/mac/web/android/etc spice clients.

Comment: For me fork different syntax `virt-viewer -c qemu+ssh://root@centos-host/system gentoo-vm`

Comment: But it anyway graphical console (with text inside). So mouse lock and no text copy&paste.

Answer (score 0):

**For grub v1 on my legacy CentOS 5 system**

In /boot/grub/grub.cfg
in start section where

```
default=0
timeout=5
```

I added

```
serial --unit=0 --speed=115200
terminal --timeout=10 console serial
```

Also I add kernel parameters to see kernel messages on `virsh console`

```
kernel <... skip ...> console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
```

Reboot guest and it works.

Found in [Zelut's Blog](https://blog.zelut.org/2010/05/05/configure-serial-console-access-on-centos-5/)